# How to set focus on a control after postback call in asp.net core razor page

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

am calling a Post method of my page model on button click using "**asp-page-handler"**, after execution am returning the page(**return Page()**) which reloads the page and the focus is automatically set to top of the page.Here I want to set focus to button I clicked. Is there any possibilities to do this. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the url of the Post handler is `https://localhost:44360/Contact?handler=Test`, then the blow script will focus the related button:

```
@section scripts{
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(function () {
                    var id = 'a[href!="' + getUrlParameter('handler') + '"]';
                    //$('a[href!="Test"]').focus();
                    $(id).focus();
                });
            });

            var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
                var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
                    sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
                    sParameterName,
                    i;

                for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
                    sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

                    if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                        return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
                    }
                }
            };
        </script>
    }
```